# Visual Studio for Mac doesn't find Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial class in Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to test the new Visual feature (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/beautiful-material-design-android-ios/) in Xamarin.Forms but I'm having an issue on Android.

I followed the instructions on the tutorial. The iOS project is working well but, in Android, for some reason I get the following error in MainActivity.cs:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'FormsMaterial' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;

namespace Test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState); # <-- error here
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

I installed Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material correctly.

The article says that the Android project must use FormsAppCompatActivity, Android Support Libraries 28.0.0 or greater, Target Android Framework 9.0 and Minimum Android Version 5.0 or greater. My project meets all the requirements.

Xamarin.Forms version: 3.6.220655
Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material version: 3.6.0.344457.

Comment: Have you tried Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material` version: `3.6.0.344457` requires `Xamarin.Forms (>= 3.6.0.344457)`, you can see this infromation under the dependencies.

Update your `xamarin.forms` version to `3.6.0.344457` would solve it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried using 3.6.0.344457 version for Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material and I still getting the same error. The intellisense is not recognizing FormsMaterial class on Android. On iOS it's working fine.

Comment: I solved the problem. I forgot to change Target Framework in Project Options -> Build -> General. It was in Android 8.1 and it must be in 9.0.

Thank you very much for your help!